Failing to overfit polynomial regression?
I am trying to overfit polynomial regression to a sine curve. As far as I've understood, when having N data samples and a polynomial degree of N-1 then the curve should go through all the data points, however, in my example this doesn't happen.
My code is below:
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

N = 50
deg = 49

X = X = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N).reshape(-1, 1)
X = np.sort(X, axis=0)
y = np.sin(X) + np.random.randn(N, 1) * 0.2

poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=deg, include_bias=False)

X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_poly, y)

y_vals = reg.predict(X_poly)

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, y_vals, color='r')
plt.show()


Can you explain what I'm misunderstanding here?

I think the fit is poor due to rounding errors. If you lower the number of samples to 10 and the degree to 9, you get a perfect fit.
But the poor quality of the fit indeed surprised me. It is coming from np.linalg.lstsq which is used under the hood by LinearRegression. You can see the differences of various implementations using the following code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

N = 50
deg = 49

X = X = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N).reshape(-1, 1)
X = np.sort(X, axis=0)
y = np.sin(X) + np.random.randn(N, 1) * 0.2

poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=deg, include_bias=True)
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X)

beta_blue = np.linalg.solve(X_poly.transpose().dot(X_poly), X_poly.transpose().dot(y))
y_blue = X_poly.dot(beta_blue)

beta_green = np.linalg.lstsq(X_poly, y, rcond=0)[0]  # rcond=None, rcond=-1
y_green = X_poly.dot(beta_green)

beta_magenta = np.linalg.pinv(X_poly.transpose().dot(X_poly)).dot(X_poly.transpose().dot(y))
y_magenta = X_poly.dot(beta_magenta)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_poly, y)
y_vals = reg.predict(X_poly)

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, y_vals, color='r')
plt.plot(X, y_blue, color='b')
plt.plot(X, y_green, color='g')
plt.plot(X, y_magenta, color='m')
plt.show()


The red curve does not start at zero because LinearRegression fits an extra intercept. So np.linalg.solve seems to be much less sensitive to ill conditioning than the other methods, at least in this case. It provides a perfect fit if you remove the noise (set 0.2 to 0.0) while the other methods still fail.
Only np.linalg.solve works even after turning off the noise by using this line in the above code:
y = np.sin(X) + np.random.randn(N, 1) * 0.2



I didn't expect the difference to be that large between implementations. Thanks for detailing.
